# How can I recover a lost MBR/boot sector?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, mbr, gparted, bootsector

I had a VDI (VirtualBox Virtual Disk Image) with Ubuntu 11.10 (64bit, I think) installed on it. Earlier, while running a GParted live CD on my Virtual Machine to erase the partition table of another Disk, I ended up inadvertently removing the partition table of my Ubuntu VDI instead of the other disk's (I know, it was stupid of me not to be 100% sure of which disk I was working on before proceeding, but I had done it so many times before that I did not even think of checking).

After gathering my bearings, I tried to look for a way to recover from the damage. I managed to recover my `/dev/sda1` partition and the swap partition (even though it was now out of the extended partition it was into before) using [TestDisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk).

The problem is that now, when I boot into the VDI, I just get a black screen with no prompts nor any signs of life.

I tried to install TestDisk's MBR onto the disk and now when I ran the VM it would display TestDisk's MBR prompt. When I told it to boot into my Ubuntu partition, though, it kept displaying that black screen.

**Is there a way to overcome this situation?** I think the problem might be lying inside the partition's boot sector (and now I'll also have to reinstall GRUB or something over the MBR).

---

EDIT: Here's some additional information.

**fdisk**:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 75.0 GB, 75019321344 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9120 cylinders, total 146522112 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/Physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e56c7

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   129746943    64872448   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       129746944   146518015     8385536    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       129748992   146518015     8384512   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

I'm not completely sure about this (and please excuse my ignorance if I'm wrong), but I think it might be an anomaly that `/dev/sda1` starts at `2048`. Shouldn't it start at `0`?

Comment: The MBR starts at 0, so sda1 must start somwhat later. Use `hexdump -C /dev/sda | more` to see what's between the MBR and sda1.

Comment: I can't discern much from it seeing it that way, but I can see that there's a gap (filled with `NOP`s) between `0x40` (included) and `0x70` (not included), and another one between `0x200` and `0x600`.

[Here's a screenshot of the dump](http://gabrielecirulli.com/p/20120529-221730.png)

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution to this problem. Here are the steps I've taken for future reference and in the hope that it might help those who encounter the same problem.

- I downloaded a Live CD version of Ubuntu 11.10 **(make sure that you download the amd64 Live CD if your system is 64 bit)**.
- I booted into the Live CD, asked to try Ubuntu and opened a new terminal window.
- Loosely following the guide published [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2011/07/install-grub-2-on-ubuntu-from-live-cd.html), I ran the following commands:

  - `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`
  - `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
  - `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
  - `sudo mount --bind /etc /mnt/etc`
  - `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
    (some of these might be redundant but I found that some programs would give out some errors if these weren't run)
  - `sudo chroot /mnt`
- When I was in as **root**, I ran:
  `grub-install /dev/sda`.

The last command said everything was okay and working. I rebooted the Virtual Machine and I was back into my Ubuntu install, as if nothing ever happened.